# yum groupinstall 'Gnome Desktop' leads to Error: Kernel conflict

Tags: linux, kernel, centos7

When trying to groupinstall 'Gnome Desktop' or 'Server with GUI' I receive an error

Error: kernel-ml-tools-libs conflicts with kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64

Error: kernel-ml-tools conflicts with kernel-tools-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64

Any ideas on how to remove the conflicting Kernels there or?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this run the following

sudo yum remove kernel-headers-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 kernel-tools-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 && sudo yum groupinstall 'Gnome Desktop'

Comment: That fixed it for me, but what does removing those do?